# Store deduplicated list of non-ascii characters in array

Tags: arrays, powershell, ascii

I have many textfiles containing extended ascii characters. I would like to build a deduplicated list of these characters, for instance:

```
á
ö
¿
```

I am able to read files and strip out the basic ascii characters. However, since I am new to Powershell, how can I break each line into characters, compare them to an existing list of characters found and output a deduplicated list of non-basic ascii chars?

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\me\Desktop\ascii" -filter "*.txt"
Foreach ($file in $files) {
    $newfile = @()

    Get-Content  $file.fullname | Foreach-Object  {
        $newfile += [string]([char[]]$_ | where-object {[int]$_ -lt 127})
    }
    Write-Host $newfile
}
```

[edit 1] Getting there...

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\me\Desktop\ascii" -filter "*.txt"
$array = @()

Foreach ($file in $files) {
    Get-Content  $file.fullname | Foreach-Object  {
        $line  = [string]([char[]]$_ | where-object {[int]$_ -lt 127}) -split '\s+' | Foreach {
            If ($array -notcontains $_) {
                $array.Add($_)
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

[edit 2] This ^^^ works in PS 4 but not in 2 (which I have on my server)? Any help in writing the PS2 compatible version of this?

[edit 3] I found out that using `$array = @()` works fine on V2 and V4 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but shouldn't you check for values *greater* than 127 if you're building a list of *extended* ASCII characters?

This should give you a list of extended ASCII characters from all files without duplicates:

```psh
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\ascii' -filter '*.txt' |
  Get-Content |
  % { [char[]]$_ } |
  ? { [int]$_ -gt 127 } |
  select -Unique
```

Comment: FYI, there is no need to quote either the path or the filter argument (unless they have spaces). It's just pointless, extra typing.  ;-)

Comment: True, but there are other situations where quotes *must* be used, even if the string doesn't contain spaces (for instance assignments: `$pattern = '*.txt'`). Thus I'm making it a habit to always use quotes around string literals. Plus, it helps with syntax highlighting. ;)

Comment: `$pattern = '*.txt'` is expression parsing and I think most folks would expect to quote in this scenario.  I just think we (top answerers) should present PowerShell as simple to use as is possible. Given its huge surface area, it needs a little help in this regard. Anyway, still a +1 for this answer.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Any help? (requires V3)

```
$string = 'áTestáöö¿'

$ht = @{}

$basic,$extended = ([char[]]$string).Where({[int]$_ -lt 127},'Split')
$extended | foreach {$ht[$_] += $null}

[string]$basic

$ht.keys
T e s t
¿
ö
á
```